# Pictureboxes on all forms don't update

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

I have many forms opened ( same new form again and again ). They all al pictureboxes and should update automatically. But, when I launch more than one, the picturebox on the forms other than the last selected/clicked/active ones do not update visually.. all the code works fine. But, when I click on one of those forms, it updates as it should be. This will make it more clear : http://i50.tinypic.com/2csaooh.jpg
If you observe closely ( or I know it.. ) only the first form on the left is updating, the pictureboxes in the others arent..
If any extra information is required. I will provide it.

The paint event contains many of e.graphics.draw...(...); codes.. thats it.. And I update the background all the time ( I put the background property.. not an image as a background ).

Comment: It would help to know, how you update the PictureBoxes. Maybe a call to `Invalidate()` can help.

Comment: I do use picturebox.Invalidate(); at the end of the paint event of the picturebox.

Comment: So you draw the pictures again and again?

Comment: Exactly. They are being drawn non-stop and mostly keep changing..

Comment: And.. I should call that from where ? Coz If I put this FormMain fr; in outside and fr.Picturebox.Invalidate(); inside the paint event, gives me and error.. Btw.. Im using c# not vb.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Invalidate()` only works on controls that are focussed. It seems, there is no nice way to force a repaint of unfocussed controls.

However, the problem can be solved with a timer, although this is pretty dirty:

```
private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(t_Tick), null, 0, 100);
}

private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Dispose();
}

void t_Tick(object sender)
{
    pictureBox1.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        pictureBox1.Update();
    });
}
```

Maybe you should consider adding all controls to the same window. Your screenshot does not look like there is a need for multiple windows.

Comment: I have no problems invalidating a PictureBox control on an unfocused form.  (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: Strange, I created a test project and experienced the same problems as HooCraX. Have you done anything different than painting and `Invalidate()`ing in the `Paint` event?

Comment: You are right at the adding all to one window but you see its like 2.5 k lines of code and around 500 lines bound to controls so.. Would take hell lot of a time to do it.. Im tryin your solution and no, Im not the down voter..

Comment: I added a PictureBox to form2, changed the PictureBox modifier to Internal, then in button click event on form1, called `f2.pictureBox1.Invalidate()` where I was painting the DateTime.Now.ToString() and the time kept changing in the unfocused PictureBox.

Comment: @HooCraX Why do you think so?  It's c#.  And it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Well whatever.. The solution doesnt seem to work.. One strange thing I noticed, when I move one of those forms, all the other update ! Can it be because of the theme ??

Comment: Have you added the event handlers? I did not mention that because I thought it to be obvious.

Comment: Yes ofc I did.. :(. Btw, all these forms update within themselves and not from other forms @LarsTech.

Comment: @HooCraX How does a form update itself?  Maybe you should update your question with some code.

Comment: @LarsTech Inside the paint event there are many e.graphics.draw...(...); Thats it..